# Django Cannot assign "'Pizza'": "Order.Food_Name" must be a "Foods" instance

Tags: python, django

Hello Guys  I am working on a restaurant project which allow user to select food item and book an order but i am getting this error as i try to book an order
 "Django Cannot assign "'Pizza'": "Order.Food_Name" must be a "Foods" instance."
 
I am using drop down menu to select food items i am using django version 2.1.5 . Please Help
views.py

```
def place_order(request):
name = request.POST["user"]
food_items = request.POST['food_item']
qty = request.POST['qty']
rating = request.POST['ratings']
price = Foods.Food_Price

order = Order(Date=datetime.date, Name_of_Person=name,Food_Name=food_items, Qty=qty, Total=price, Ratings=rating)
order.save()

return render(request, "index.html")
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models


class Foods(models.Model):
    Food_Number = models.IntegerField(null=False,)
    Food_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, null=False)
    Food_Qty = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Food_Price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Food_Number} - {self.Food_Name} {self.Food_Price}"


class Order(models.Model):
    Order_id = models.AutoField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    Date = models.DateField()
    Name_of_Person = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=40)
    Food_Name = models.ForeignKey(Foods, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qty = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Total = models.IntegerField()
    Ratings = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Order_id} - {self.Name_of_Person} |{self.Food_Name} |{self.Total}"
```

What can i do solve this error

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your `Order` model `Food_Name` is foreign-key field. So you need to assign model-instance which is Food in this case to this field. But you are assigning `food_items = request.POST['food_item']` which is suppose to be food_name string i guess. That is why this error raise. I don't think your model is properly design. `Food_Name` is not an unique id field in `Food` model rather in your `Order` table you would like to have `Food` not `Food_name`.